# JavaScript: How can I split a decimal number into 2 part according to where the first zero occurs after a non-zero integer

Tags: javascript

Sorry if the title sounds confusing. Basically what I am trying to do is to split a decimal number like this `0.1000` into two part - 1. `0.1` and `000` so I can render them differently with different styles.

Check out this screenshot [image]

All the numbers are represented in strings. The tricky part is that we cannot split the number using `number.split('0')` since we only want to split at the first zero that appears after a non-zero integer.

Not sure how I can do this.

Comment: What will be the output for `1.0000`?

Comment: @adiga it is in the screenshot

Comment: what's wrong with just go checking where is the `0`?

Comment: Does this work `number.match(/([\d.]+?)(0*)$/).slice(1)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
const number = 1.2345670089

let renderStyle1 = ''
let renderStyle2 = ''
 
const string = String(number) + '.'
const parts = string.split('.')
const decimals = parts[1]
const decimalsArray = Array.from(decimals);

// From MDN: The findIndex() method returns the index of the first element in the array that satisfies the provided testing function. Otherwise -1 is returned.
const firstIndexOfZero = decimalsArray.findIndex(x => x === '0'); 

// From MDN: The slice() method returns a shallow copy of a portion of an array into a new array object selected from start to end (end not included) where start and end represent the index of items in that array. The original array will not be modified.

if(firstIndexOfZero === -1){
   renderStyle1 =  parts[0] + parts[1]
} else {
      renderStyle1 =  parts[0] + decimalsArray.slice(0, firstIndexOfZero).join('')  // using .join method to convert array to string without commas   
      renderStyle2 = decimalsArray.slice(firstIndexOfZero, decimalsArray.length).join('')  // using .join method to convert array to string without commas 
}

console.log(renderStyle1) // "1234567"
console.log(renderStyle2) // "0089"
```

Answer (score 2):

If I did not misunderstand what you are trying to achieve, you can do it with a regex that only matches unlimited zeros that are at the end of the given string like follows:

```js
function markNumber(num) {
    return num.replace( /(0{1,})$/g, '<span>$1</span>')
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Messy, and, probably, can be improved, but this should work:

```js
let re = /(\d*\.[1-9]*?)(0.*)/;
["1000", "1.01", "1.10", "1.000", "1.34043"].map((str) =>
  str.split(re).filter((entry) => entry !== "")
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's my regex function

```js
const number = ['0.1000', '2.534300', '1.2000', '1.004334000'];

function split_float(num) {
  const reg = /^(\d*\.\d*[^0])(0*)$/g;
  const [, ...matches] = [...num.matchAll(reg)][0];
  
  return matches;
}

console.log(number.map(split_float));
```

Answer (score 0):

here is my answer. It uses split and substring to achieve what you want. Tried it in w3school's tryit editor. Handles all of your data in screenshot pretty well:

```
function myFunction() {
  var str = "0.01200";
  var partone = str.split(".")[0];
  var temp = str.split(".")[1];
  for (var i=0; i<temp.length; i++){
    if (temp[i] != 0 && temp[i+1] == 0){
        break;
    }
  }
  var parttwo = temp.substring(i+1);
  partone = partone + "." + temp.substring(0, i+1);
  var res = "partOne = " + partone + " and partTwo = " + parttwo;
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = res;
}
```

Here is the screenshot:
[image]